# Where can I obtain a Typhoon Fleet Issue

Tags: eve-online

Where can you obtain this ship? I checked the Republic's LP store and I can only find a Tempest Republic Fleet issue.

Are there different loyalty stores or is this ship discontinued?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This post](http://www.eveonline.com/ingameboard.asp?a=topic&threadID=1276070) suggests that it is sold by the [Tribal Liberation Force](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tribal_Liberation_Force_%28NPC_corporation%29), not the Republic Fleet.  Or as with anything else, by whoever wants to put it up on a item exchange (sell) contract.

If you buy it from [their LP store](http://www.ellatha.com/eve/lp/Tribal-Liberation-Force), it's a stock 'phoon, plus 150,000 LP and a [Minmatar UUC Nexus Chip](http://eve-central.com/home/quicklook.html?typeid=17814), which seems to be the easy part (6-8 mil ISK) compared to the LP.

Comment: Factional Warfare corp. makes my life harer. well, i will have to go with your option 2

Answer (score 4):

All faction battleships were moved into the LP stores for the faction warfare corps when faction warfare was introduced.  FW has its own consequences you'll need to be prepared for.  TLF (in the selected answer) is that for Minnie, but the same issue will arise for CN Ravens, FedNavy Domis, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

All ships are also market-legal these days, so Typhoon Fleet Issue is, too, available on open market.